# What's the rule about using I first in a sentence with multiple noun or pronouns?

Tags: syntactic-analysis, linguistics

A sentence can be written as

> I and my friends

And

> My friends and I

There are several references for both sentences but I want to know the rule for the first one.

Comment: #1 is considered wrong in English-speaking countries, because it's rude to put myself first, culturally. That's all.